# Swift2 - Sort multiple arrays based on the sorted order of another INT array

Tags: arrays, swift2, sorting

```
let points:[Int] = [200, 1000, 100, 500]
let people:[String] = ["Harry", "Jerry", "Hannah", "John"]
let peopleIds:[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let sex:[String] = ["Male", "Male", "Female", "Male"]
```

How can I sort this arrays by points to be?:

```
let points:[Int] = [1000, 500, 200, 100]
let people:[String] = ["Jerry", "John", "Harry", "Hannah"]
let peopleIds:[Int] = [2, 4, 1, 3]
let sex:[String] = ["Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"]
```

It's not duplicate of [How to sort 1 array in Swift / Xcode and reorder multiple other arrays by the same keys changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273805/how-to-sort-1-array-in-swift-xcode-and-reorder-multiple-other-arrays-by-the-sa)
I've tried with the answers and it's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new array of indexes sorted the way you want "descending" and then map the other arrays.

```
var points:[Int] = [200, 1000, 100, 500]
var people:[String] = ["Harry", "Jerry", "Hannah", "John"]
var peopleIds:[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var sex:[String] = ["Male", "Male", "Female", "Male"]


//descending order array of indexes
let sortedOrder = points.enumerate().sort({$0.1>$1.1}).map({$0.0})

//Map the arrays based on the new sortedOrder
points = sortedOrder.map({points[$0]})
people = sortedOrder.map({people[$0]})
peopleIds = sortedOrder.map({peopleIds[$0]})
sex = sortedOrder.map({sex[$0]})
```

I just tested this solution out and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution with your own data.

```
let points:[Int] = [200, 1000, 100, 500]
let people:[String] = ["Harry", "Jerry", "Hannah", "John"]
let peopleIds:[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let sex:[String] = ["Male", "Male", "Female", "Male"]

let sortedPointsEnumerateIndexes = points.enumerate().sort { $0.element > $1.element}.map { $0.index }


var sortedPoints:[Int] = []
var sortedPeople:[String] = []
var sortedPeopleIds:[Int] = []
var sortedSex:[String] = []

for i in sortedPointsEnumerateIndexes {
    sortedPoints.append(points[i])
    sortedPeople.append(people[i])
    sortedPeopleIds.append(peopleIds[i])
    sortedSex.append(sex[i])
}

print(sortedPoints)     // [1000, 500, 200, 100]
print(sortedPeople)     // ["Jerry", "John", "Harry", "Hannah"]
print(sortedPeopleIds)  // [2, 4, 1, 3]
print(sortedSex)        // ["Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"]

// with map
let sorted2Point = sortedPointsEnumerateIndexes.map{ points[$0] }
let sorted2People = sortedPointsEnumerateIndexes.map{ people[$0] }
// ....

print(sorted2Point)     // [1000, 500, 200, 100]
print(sorted2People)    // ["Jerry", "John", "Harry", "Hannah"]
```