# Swift Map ARRAYS by Date Array

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Im trying to accomplish this: [[Swift2 - Sort multiple arrays based on the sorted order of another INT array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637970/swift2-sort-multiple-arrays-based-on-the-sorted-order-of-another-int-array][1])
But I have to sort by NSDate array.

```
// dates are actual NSDates, I pasted strings into my sample
var dates:[NSDate] = [2019-12-20 13:00 +0000, 2019-12-20 13:00 +0000, 2019-12-12 13:00 +0000]
var people:[String] = ["Harry", "Jerry", "Hannah"]
var peopleIds:[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]


// the following line doesn't work.
// i tried a few variations with enumerated instead of enumerate and sorted instead of sort
// but with now luck
let sortedOrder = dates.enumerate().sort({$0.1>$1.1}).map({$0.0})

dates = sortedOrder.map({points[$0]})
people = sortedOrder.map({people[$0]})
peopleIds = sortedOrder.map({peopleIds[$0]})
```

Comment: `Date` conforms to `Comparable` protocol since Swift 3.0. so you can simply sort your dates `dates.sorted(by: >)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dates declaration from `NSDate` to `Date`. `Date` conforms to `Comparable` protocol since Swift 3.0. Doing so you can simply sort your dates `dates.sorted(by: >)`. To sort your arrays together you can zip your arrays, sort it by dates and map the sorted elements:

```
let sortedZip = zip(dates, zip(people, peopleIds)).sorted { $0.0 > $1.0}
let sortedPeople = sortedZip.map{ $0.1.0 }
let sortedIDs = sortedZip.map{ $0.1.1 }
```

Comment: Hi Leo. Thanx I just tried that, but get this warning: Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'NSDate' operands. I guess I could try to add an additional array to convert the dates to plain numbers if there is no other way.

Comment: @MartinVidic add `as Date` after each date so `{$0.0 as Date > $1.0 as Date}`

Comment: @MartinVidic Change your dates declaration from `NSDate` to `Date`. You should use only Swift native classes

Comment: @LeoDabus `NSDate` bridges directly to `Date` and vice versa as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate). A simple cast can fix the issue as well

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath There is no reason/advantage to work with NSDate in Swift

Comment: @LeoDabus agreed unless perhaps you are trying to work with `CFDate`s

Comment: A better approach if OP insist in using NSDate is to make it conform to Comparable as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sort associated fields you should really consider using an object oriented approach using some kind of model, however, the following should achieve what you are trying to do:

```swift
var n = min(dates.count, people.count, peopleIds.count)
var tuples = (0 ..< n).map { (dates[$0], people[$0], peopleIds[$0]) }
    .sorted { $0.0 as Date > $1.0 as Date }
dates = tuples.map{ $0.0 }
people = tuples.map{ $0.1 }
peopleIds = tuples.map{ $0.2 }
```