# Swift : Sorting three arrays based on a particular array

Tags: swift, sorting

I have these three array :

```
let codesArray = ["de_DE", "en_US", "en-GB", "es_ES"]
let localesArray = ["Deutsch", "English", "English UK", "Español"]
let internationalsArray = ["German", "English", "British English", "Spanish"]
```

I would like to sort the internationalsArray and sort the others based on internationalsArray, so that I will obtain :

```
codesArraySorted = [ "en-GB",  "en_US", "de_DE", "es_ES"]
localesArraySorted = [ "English UK",  "English", "Deutsch",  "Español"]
internationalsArraySorted = ["British English", "English", "German", "Spanish"]
```

I tried with `sort()`, `isOrderedBefore` but no success.

Can you give me an idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Create a struct to hold your information (each country) to group en-GB with English UK then sort that array. Why do you need to manage three separate arrays?

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I need to keep arrays in order to use some of builtin methods and library... It will not work with struct or dictionaries...

Comment: You can always map an array of structs to get a new array that contains just the relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in Swift we should not name a variable (or constant) after its type, so:

```
let codes = ["de_DE", "en_US", "en-GB", "es_ES"]
let locales = ["Deutsch", "English", "English UK", "Español"]
let internationals = ["German", "English", "British English", "Spanish"]
```

Now let's build an array of indexes looking at how `codes` should be sorted

```
let indexes = codes.enumerate().sort { $0.element < $1.element }.map { $0.index }
```

> The `indexes` array contains `[0, 2, 1, 3]`, the `i-th` element into this array represents the position the `i-th` of `codes` **should** have.

So now we can sort each array based on indexes

```
let sortedCodes = codes.enumerate().sort { indexes[$0.0] < indexes[$1.0] }.map { $0.element }
let sortedLocales = locales.enumerate().sort { indexes[$0.0] < indexes[$1.0] }.map { $0.element }
let sortedInternationals = internationals.enumerate().sort { indexes[$0.0] < indexes[$1.0] }.map { $0.element }
```

Output

```
sortedCodes // ["de_DE", "en-GB", "en_US", "es_ES"]
sortedLocales // ["Deutsch", "English UK", "English", "Español"]
sortedInternationals // ["German", "British English", "English", "Spanish"]
```

That's it.

Comment: That is the way I was waiting for ! (used many times in Matlab)

Answer (score 2):

You should put this information into a custom struct. Then you can put instances of this struct type into an array and sort the array:

```
struct Language {
    let code: String
    let locale: String
    let international: String
}

let languages = [
    Language(code: "de_DE", locale: "Deutsch", international: "German"),
    Language(code: "en_US", locale: "English", international: "English"),
    Language(code: "en-GB", locale: "English UK", international: "British English"),
    Language(code: "es_ES", locale: "Español", international: "Spanish")
]

let sorted = languages.sort { $0.international < $1.international }
print(sorted)
```

You can then use the `map` method to extract the original information:

```
let codesArraySorted = sorted.map { $0.code }
let localesArraySorted = sorted.map { $0.locale }
let internationalsArraySorted = sorted.map { $0.international }
```

Comment: Thank you, I implement this answer, because it is the most understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zip3 function 
https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/04dbc470e17f67f836a2#file-zip-swift if you don't want to implement your own struct or dictionary.

```
let codesArray = ["de_DE", "en_US", "en-GB", "es_ES"]
let localesArray = ["Deutsch", "English", "English UK", "Español"]
let internationalsArray = ["German", "English", "British English", "Spanish"]

let combined = zip3(internationalsArray, b: localesArray, c: codesArray).sort {$0.0 < $1.0}

// use map to extract the individual arrays
let internationalsArraySorted = combined.map {$0.0}
let localesArraySorted = combined.map {$0.1}
let codesArraySorted = combined.map {$0.2}

print(internationalsArraySorted)  // "["British English", "English", "German", "Spanish"]\n"
print(localesArraySorted)  // "["English UK", "English", "Deutsch", "Español"]\n"
print(codesArraySorted)  // "["en-GB", "en_US", "de_DE", "es_ES"]\n"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did not fully undestand this zip3 function, due to its lack of documentation. Maybe it is a well known feature in other languages

Comment: Zip is also included in Swift. http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/func/zip/. It tells that the 1st element of all arrays are related like de_DE, Deutsch and German are one component. It is used to solve exactly what your trying to ache with just one line of code. Its a type functional paradigm.

Comment: it is look like combine multiples arrays into a structure, interesting !

Comment: Yea it is a functional way of solving problem. The other two answers does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it that avoids sorting multiple times and will also allow you to update your original variables if you want to:

```
var codes = ["de_DE", "en_US", "en-GB", "es_ES"]
var locales = ["Deutsch", "English", "English UK", "Español"]
var internationals = ["German", "English", "British English", "Spanish"]

(codes,locales,internationals) = {( $0.map{codes[$0]}, 
                                    $0.map{locales[$0]}, 
                                    $0.map{internationals[$0]} 
                                 )} 
(codes.enumerated().sorted{$0.1<$1.1}.map{$0.0})
```

[EDIT] You may also want to check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35274250/5237560
for a more elegant notation.