# Sorting 2 arrays the same way in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array for item names, and another for item prices. I want to sort the prices from least to greatest, but have the appropriate items and the prices be at the same index.

For example:
[9, 4, 1] & ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"] -> [1, 4, 9] & ["item 3", "item 2", "item 1"]

Any idea how i could do this efficiently for large arrays?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg&feature=youtu.be&t=7m10s

Comment: See answer to same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273805/how-to-sort-1-array-in-swift-xcode-and-reorder-multiple-other-arrays-by-the-sa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
let prices = [9, 4, 1]
let names = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
```

### Solution #1

You can

```
let sorted = zip(prices, names).sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }

let sortedPrices = sorted.map { $0.0 } // [1, 4, 9]
let sortedNames = sorted.map { $0.1 } // ["item 3", "item 2", "item 1"]
```

### Solution #2

You should really use a model value.

```
let prices = [9, 4, 1]
let names = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]

struct Item {
    let name: String
    let price: Int
}

let sortedItems = zip(names, prices).map(Item.init).sorted { $0.price < $1.price }

// [Item(name: "item 3", price: 1), Item(name: "item 2", price: 4), Item(name: "item 1", price: 9)]
```